# MySQL: Alias table doesn't exists (complicated subqueries)

Tags: mysql

This is part of a (very) **bigger** query.

The error is the missing alias "clienti_con_rinnovo" (Table "clienti_con_rinnovo" does not exists). I don't need to rewrite the query (the logic is right) but probably an help to get that aliases.

If interesting (but you know yet) the order is `LEFT JOIN` and following the `UNION`.

Thank you in advance

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT
    id,
    MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
    FROM transactions
    WHERE
    renew IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY id ) AS clienti_con_rinnovo

UNION                                           

SELECT * FROM

    ( SELECT
            id,
            MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
      FROM transactions
      WHERE renew IS NULL
      GROUP BY id ) AS clienti_senza_rinnovo

      LEFT JOIN clienti_con_rinnovo ON clienti_con_rinnovo.id = clienti_senza_rinnovo.id
      WHERE clienti_con_rinnovo.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to create a view, so you dont need to load huge amounts of data into a result each time you perform that query. Also easier to maintain since you can filter inside the view or delete columns you dont need anymore.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW clienti_con_rinnovo
AS
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
    FROM transactions
    WHERE
    renew IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY id
```

But your attempt is almost working. Try:

```
SELECT clienti_con_rinnovo.* FROM
( SELECT
    id,
    MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
    FROM transactions
    WHERE
    renew IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY id ) AS clienti_con_rinnovo
```

and the same for your other table:

```
SELECT clienti_senza_rinnovo.* FROM
    ( SELECT
            id,
            MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
      FROM transactions
      WHERE renew IS NULL
      GROUP BY id ) AS clienti_senza_rinnovo
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but aliases don't work the way you are trying to implement it here. 
Try using this

```
SELECT * FROM
 ( SELECT
 id,
 MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
 FROM transactions
 WHERE
 renew IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY id ) AS clienti_con_rinnovo_new

 UNION

 SELECT clienti_senza_rinnovo.* FROM 
 ( SELECT
   id,
   MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
     FROM transactions
    WHERE
    renew IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY id ) AS clienti_con_rinnov
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
   id,
  MAX(dateTransaction) AS last_transaction_renew
  FROM transactions
  WHERE renew IS NULL
  GROUP BY id ) AS clienti_senza_rinnovo ON clienti_con_rinnovo.id = 
  clienti_senza_rinnovo.id 
  WHERE clienti_con_rinnovo.id IS NULL
```

Comment: WITH is not supported from MySql specifically from my version, cannot use it

Comment: will add a work arond in a minute can be solved with sub queries